# differences between new char[n] and new (char[n])

Tags: c++, memory-management

Is there any difference between `new char[n]` and `new (char[n])`?

I have the second case in a generated code, g++ (4.8.0) gives me

```
ISO C++ does not support variable-length array types [-Wvla]
```

This makes me think if these two are the same or not.

1. `new char[n]` means "allocate `n` objects of type `char`.
2. does `new (char[n])` mean "allocate 1 object of type `array of n chars`"?
3. deleting the first is clear.
4. should I delete the second with `delete` or `delete[]`?
5. are there any other differences I should be aware of?
6. may I safely remove the parentheses and turn the second case into the first, when other parts of the software expect the second?

The code is generated by a third party software (and used by other parts of the software), so I cannot just "use vector instead".

This is minimal example:

```
int main (void)
{
    int n(10);
    int *arr = new (int[n]); // removing parentheses fixes warning
    *arr = 0; // no "unused variable" warning
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the compiler and version?

Comment: gcc 4.8.0, added to the question

Comment: I'm surprised it allows the conversion from `int(*)[n]` to `int*`.

Comment: @aschepler I think VLAs have type of `int*`. They `int(*)[n]` can't exist as a type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between char\[\] and new char\[\] when using constant lengths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226680/difference-between-char-and-new-char-when-using-constant-lengths)

Comment: Oh, I see.  "When the allocated object is an array (that is, the noptr-new-declarator syntax is used or the new-type-id or type-id denotes an array type), the new-expression yields a pointer to the initial element (if any) of the array."

Comment: Also see http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=4498

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The basic issue here is that C++ does not allow an array bound `[n]` to be used in a type unless `n` is a constant expression.  g++ and some other compilers will sometimes allow it anyway, but it's impossible to get consistent behavior when you start mixing variable-length-arrays and templates.

The apparent exception `int* p = new int[n];` works because here the `[n]` is syntactically part of the `new` expression, not part of the type provided to the `new`, and `new` does "know how" to create arrays with length determined at runtime.

```
// can be "constexpr" in C++11:
const int C = 12;

int main() {
    int* p1 = new int[C];
    int* p2 = new (int[C]);
    typedef int arrtype[C];
    int* p3 = new arrtype;

    int n = 10;
    int* p4 = new int[n];
    // int* p5 = new (int[n]);  // Illegal!
    // typedef int arrtype2[n]; // Illegal!
    // int* p6 = new arrtype2;

    delete[] p1;
    delete[] p2;
    delete[] p3;
    delete[] p4;
}
```

Semantically, though, after any final `[C]` is used to convert a type into an array type, the new expression only cares about whether it's dealing with an array or not.  All the requirements about type of the expression, whether to use `new[]` and `delete[]`, and so on say things like "when the allocated type is an array", not "when the array new syntax is used".  So in the example above, the initializations of `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` are all equivalent, and in all cases `delete[]` is the correct deallocation form.

The initialization of `p4` is valid, but the code for `p5` and `p6` is not correct C++.  g++ would allow them anyway when not using `-pedantic`, and by analogy I'd expect the initializations for `p4`, `p5`, and `p6` to also all be equivalent.  @MM's disassembly supports that conclusion.

So yes, it should be a safe improvement to remove the "extra" parentheses from this sort of expression.  And the correct deletion is the `delete[]` type.

Comment: In your answer i see sort of the same "T [n] does not denote a type if n is not constant" which @Kerrek in his answer does too. I cannot see why that should be the case, there is no such rule in C++. new accepts denoted runtime dependent *type* specifiers, here.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I'm confused. `[` _constant-expression_ _opt_ `]` is part of the syntax for a _declarator_ or _type-id_.  (dcl.decl/4 _noptr-declarator_; dcl.name/1 _noptr-abstract-declarator_ and _noptr-abstract-pack-declarator_)  Do you have an example where `n` is not a constant expression and `T[n]` is a well-formed type?

Comment: yes, the new operator expression `new int[n]` is such an example. It is a well formed type specifier (new-type-id).

Comment: Oh, now I think I see your point.  Still, it's impossible for any expression or variable to have a type with non-constant array dimension.  And if I wanted to be overly picky, I might suggest it's a Standard defect that it doesn't explicitly say what type is specified by a _new-type-id_ the way it does for a _declarator_ or _type-id_.

Comment: Just wait until the runtime-sized arrays of C++14.

Comment: @dalle: We already have runtime-sized container classes.  C++14 adds a few more.  But it doesn't make any sweeping changes to the rules being discussed here, the way C99-compatible VLAs would.

Comment: The final release of C++14 did not include runtime-sized arrays, so this problem is deferred to C++17 :)

Answer (score 6):

- `new T[N]` makes an array of `N` elements of type `T`.
- `new (T[N])` makes a single object of type `T[N]`.

The effect is the same (and both expressions yield a `T *` that points to the first element of the array and needs to be deleted with `delete[]` (cf. 5.3.4/5), but clearly `T[N]` must be a valid *type* in the latter case, so `N` must be a constant expression, while in the former case it is a dynamic argument of the array-new expression.

Comment: `[]` has a higher precedence than `new` so shouldn't `new T[N]` be interpreted the same as `new (T[N])`?

Comment: The 'this one makes N elements', 'this one makes a single array' distinction doesn't exist, or at least I can't see it.

Comment: @Named: The `new T[N]` form is a different grammatical construct, and the `N` is part of the array-new expression, not of the type.

Comment: @LucDanton: The distinction is that `new T[rand()]` is valid, but `new (T[rand()])` isn't. And `T[N]` is a *type* when `N` is a constant expression.

Comment: Right, that's in your paragraph and I don't object to that. It's the bullet points. If both syntaxes are valid, they mean and do the same thing. No distinction at all.

Comment: @LucDanton: But they're different grammatical things. The first is an array-new expression, and the latter is an ordinary new expression with an array type. I'm not claiming that they mean different things.

Comment: (The standard doesn't actually call it "array-new expression", but it has some grammar details that distinguish the two forms.)

Comment: Different on the grammar level, sure. There are two ways of declaring type aliases as well, but they end up doing the same thing, too. I question how 'ordinary' is a 'new expression with an array type' given that it doesn't return `T(*)[N]`.

Comment: @LucDanton: You never get a pointer to the array, but only to its first element, because of that sentence 5 I mentioned, which explicitly says what happens when the type is an array type (including a provision for the *noptr-new-declarator* form).

Comment: I know what happens. And it's the same for both.

Comment: Both create an object of type `T [N]`. Your answer seems to state that is not the case.

Comment: It is not that one case supplies a type and another case does not. Both cases supply types. But one case supplies it by a *type-specifier* and the other case by a *new-type-specifier*. All which a text like `T [N]` can do is to *denote* or *specify* a type in one or another way (some can denote less and some more types).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Hm, yes, they certainly both supply types, but the way I think about it is that the first form supplies `T` and says "make an array of `N`", and the second form supplies `T[N]` and says "make one". The result is indeed in both cases an array of `N` elements of type `T`, as I hope I've stated.

Comment: Both create `N` distinct object of type `T`, using the array allocator.  Even if you use `typedef T T5[5]; new T5` the compiler still uses `operator new[]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
  new int [n]
  //Allocates memory for `n` x `sizeof(int)` and returns
  //the pointer which points to the beginning of it. 

 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+
 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |      |      |
 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |      |      |
 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |      |      |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+


  new (int [n])
  //Allocate a (int[n]), a square which its item is an array
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+ |
||     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |      |      | |
||     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |      |      | |
||     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |      |      | |
|+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+ |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In fact both of them are equal.

Here is the code generated by assembler (just an ignorable difference):

```
int n = 10;
int *i = new (int[n]);
int *j = new int[n];

i[1] = 123;
j[1] = 123;

----------------------------------

!    int *i = new (int[n]);
main()+22: mov    0x1c(%esp),%eax
main()+26: sub    $0x1,%eax
main()+29: add    $0x1,%eax
main()+32: shl    $0x2,%eax
main()+35: mov    %eax,(%esp)
main()+38: call   0x401620 <_Znaj> // void* operator new[](unsigned int);
main()+43: mov    %eax,0x18(%esp)
!    int *j = new int[n];
main()+47: mov    0x1c(%esp),%eax
main()+51: shl    $0x2,%eax
main()+54: mov    %eax,(%esp)
main()+57: call   0x401620 <_Znaj> // void* operator new[](unsigned int);
main()+62: mov    %eax,0x14(%esp)
!    
!    i[1] = 123;
main()+66: mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
main()+70: add    $0x4,%eax
main()+73: movl   $0x7b,(%eax)
!    j[1] = 123;
main()+79: mov    0x14(%esp),%eax
main()+83: add    $0x4,%eax
main()+86: movl   $0x7b,(%eax)
```

You must `delete` both of them by `delete [] ...`

Comment: I'd point out that `_Znaj` is g++-manglish for `void* operator new[](unsigned int);`

Comment: -1: Just because two things generate the same (or similar) assembly code for a trivial code frament doesn't mean that the code is "equal" or even equivalent; assembly is very low-level and doesn't care about types, while this entire problem is about high-level types which are only at the C++ level. Assembly dumps should only be inspected when it comes to issues of performance, NOT correctness. Consider how different they are when the type is an object with a constructor and destructor, and not just a fundamental like int or char.

Comment: @fluffy: (1) The statement about _equality_ is the result of its previous notes not following assembly descriptions. (2) Of course not, I agree we can't get the result from some assembly code about a C++ code. **BUT** assembly codes which generated by compiler are good observation to get familiar to the behavior of a piece of C++ code.

Comment: Right, but my point is that the code isn't equivalent in the first place. They just happen to have the same behavior under a very specific set of circumstances.