# Why is new int (*)[3] an error?

Tags: c++, syntax-error, new-operator

```
typedef int (*A)[3];

int (**p)[3] = new A;              // OK
int (**q)[3] = new (int(*)[3]);    // OK
int (**r)[3] = new int (*)[3];     // error
```

The error from GCC is `error: expected primary-expression before ')' token` . Why are the extra parentheses required in this expression?

Comment: Related (but not duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/q/16634713/1505939

Comment: Because a *new-type-id* may not contain parentheses. But that's of course not a satisfying answer.

Comment: Maybe this has to do with disambiguation; e.g. `new int()` could be interpreted as trying to allocate a function `int (void)`

Comment: Why would you want to dynamically allocate an array pointer anyhow? Seems like a hint that the underlying program design is needlessly complex.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard defines *new-type-id* as the longest sequence of *new-declarators*. There is also a note, which illustrates a similar situation (although it allocates pointers to functions):

> **5.3.4 New [expr.new]**
>
> ....
>
> *new-type-id:*
>       *type-specifier-seq* *new-declarator*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> *new-declarator:*
>       *ptr-operator new-declarator*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>       *noptr-new-declarator*
>
> *noptr-new-declarator:*
>       [ *expression* ] 
>   *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>       *noptr-new-declarator* 
>   [ *constant-expression* ] 
>   *attribute-specifier-seq*
>   <sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> ....
>
> The *new-type-id* in a *new-expression* is the longest possible sequence of *new-declarators*.
>   [ *Note*: this prevents ambiguities between the declarator operators `&`, `&&`, `*`, and `[]` and
>   their expression counterparts. — *end note* ] [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> new int * i; // syntax error: parsed as (new int*) i, not as (new int)*i
> ```
>
> The `*` is the pointer declarator and not the multiplication operator. — *end example* ]
>
> [ *Note*: parentheses in a *new-type-id* of a *new-expression* can
>   have surprising effects. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> new int(*[10])(); // error
> ```
>
> is ill-formed because the binding is
>
> ```
> (new int) (*[10])(); // error
> ```
>
> Instead, the explicitly parenthesized version of the `new` operator
>   can be used to create objects of compound types (3.9.2):
>
> ```
> new (int (*[10])());
> ```
>
> allocates an array of 10 pointers to functions (taking no argument and
>   returning `int`. — *end example* ] — *end note* ]

Comment: @M.M As usual, with the standard it is a bit difficult. I added some grammar constructions, but they are not complete. E.g. things like _expression_ or _attribute-specifier-seq_ are not defined here.

Comment: @AlexD *expression* would be too complicated, and *attribute-specifier-seq* is irrelevant. IMHO, the interesting part is that the *new-expression* can be either contain a (completely) parenthesized *type-id* or a(n unparenthesized) *new-type-id*, where the *new-type-id* may (as far as I can see) not contain any parentheses.

Comment: @dyp As far as I understand, _new_type_id_ may contain _expression_, which may contain parentheses, e.g. `new int [(3)]`. BTW, thanks for editing of the first post!