# Pointer to pointer to array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a variable definition `int (**ff)[4];`, which is very bad looking. If I'm right (inferred from the fact that `int (*f)[4];` is a pointer to an array of 4 int-s) this is a pointer to a pointer to an array of 4 int-s.

Now I have tried to initialize this thing but I had no success. Initializing `f` was simple (`f = new int[5][4];`), but the line `ff = new int*[6][4];` is not working. Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2013 says in an error message that

```
a value of type "int *(*)[4]" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int (**)[4]"
```

I have a very bad feeling that I really misunderstood something.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, that I didn't said it explicitly: What I wanted, is to allocate memory space for not only one, but for more pointers which later can point to an array of an array of 4 int-s. Of course I wanted this in one line without the help of any other definition, conversion etc.

Comment: You see this variable, the first thing that comes to your mind is how to initialize it? I'd dump it :)

Comment: I just experimented with the language and wanted to understand better this part of it.

Comment: See `std::array`, `std::vector`.

Comment: @Bartis Point taken.

Comment: There are hundreds of different ways to properly initialize `int (**ff)[4]`. But there's no meaningless answer to your question until you explain what you want to use that `int (**ff)[4]` for. What are you trying to do? For example, you can initialize that `ff` with your own `&f`: `int (**ff)[4] = &f;`. Done. Does this help you? No one knows....

Answer (score 4):

I can (not) see this used only in this way:

```
int (*a)[4] = new int[6][4];
int (**ff)[4] = &a;
```

`int (**ff)[4]` means "a pointer to pointer to an array of four `int`s". This means we have to have `int (*)[4]` first - an lvalue, so we can take its address with `operator&`.

On the other hand, `new int*[6][4];` allocates an array of pointers to an array of four pointers (the "outer" array decays). This is completely different type from the first one.

I had to help myself with [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) on this one.

**Edit:**

I've just made this:

```
using PTR = int (*)[4];
int (**ff)[4] = new PTR; // hooray, a dynamically allocated pointer!
```

but can't figure a way without the type alias...

Actually, there is one: `int (**ff)[4] = new (int (*)[4])`, gathered from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029277/why-is-new-int-3-an-error). Don't forget that all you have now is a dynamically allocated uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Another plan might be `typedef int A4[4]; int (**ff)[4] = new A4*[length];` and the a loop, so you allocate a 3-d array with the first 2 dimensions variable and the third dimension `4`.

Comment: @M.M I need a help out here! Can you figure out a way without a `typedef`? I've bumped into a syntax barrier.

Comment: [You're not the first to wonder about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029277/why-is-new-int-3-an-error)

Comment: I forgot about the extra-parentheses version from my own question, doh

Answer (score 0):

A double pointer is a pointer to a pointer to get the obvious out of the way. That means that it will hold the memory address of a pointer, again obvious. That means you initialise your pointer and only then point your double pointer to it. Such as,

```
int* f[] = new int[4];
int** ff = &f;
```

Then to access this you can do,

```
(*ff)[1]
```

This will allow you to access the information stored in the dynamic array.

NOTE: leave the [] beside f empty if the size is not known at compile time which is the reason you should be doing it this way in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access elements of an array a[3][3] by pointer to pointer to array than you can do that by below code :

```
int a[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int (*p)[3]=a;
int (**ff)[3]=&p;
```

To print it :

```
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<3;j++)
{
printf("%d ",ff[0][i][j]);
}
printf("\n"); 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Alan,

I think the problem here is your initial assumption is incorrect.
     *f[4] (or (*f)[4])
would actually be an array of 4 pointers to int, not a pointer to an
array of 4 ints. Then,
   **ff[4]
 would be a pointer to an array of 4 pointers to
int. I would recommend backing up a little, with this information in hand, and
trying it again. Also, an assignment to the
    **ff
would be a single pointer, and
probably not an array, depending on how you are intending to use it.

```
                            Blake Mitchell
                            retired free lance programmer
```

Comment: `int* f[4]` is an array of 4 pointers to int, `int (*f)[4]` is a pointer to array of 4 ints.

Comment: You don't need to sign off your answers - instead you can put that detail in your profile (click your name to get there)