# Warning when dynamically allocating an array of function pointers

Tags: c++, gcc, syntax, clang, language-lawyer

I want to dynamically allocate an array of function pointers. Here are some of my attempts:

```
#include <type_traits>

void f(int n) {
    // auto p1 = new void(*[n])(); // syntax error

    auto p2 = new (void(*[n])()); // warning, see below

    auto p3 = new typeof(void(*)())[n]; // non-standard extension

    using fptr = void(*)(); auto p4 = new fptr[n]; // verbose, but okay

    auto p5 = new std::add_pointer_t<void()>[n]; // hackish
}
```

I wonder why `p2` results in a warning, given that I cannot write it without parentheses (like in `p1`)?

> (gcc) warning: non-constant array new length must be specified without
> parentheses around the type-id [-Wvla]
>
> (clang) warning: when type is in parentheses, array cannot have
> dynamic size

This is a purely theoretical question. I am not looking for an advice how to write good code solving the problem.

Comment: How about `auto p6 = std::vector<std::function<void()>>();`?

Comment: Where you say "too verbose", I would say "easiest to read"

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634713/differences-between-new-charn-and-new-charn

Comment: @Eljay Yes, this is close to what I would write in practice. My question is purely theoretical though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one way to write this expression without some sort of type alias. But it's not worth it.

The grammar for *new-expression* is

> *new-expression*:
>
> `::`<sub>*opt*</sub>   *new-placement*<sub>*opt*</sub> *new-type-id* *new-initializer*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> `::`<sub>*opt*</sub>   *new-placement*<sub>*opt*</sub> `(`*type-id*`)` *new-initializer*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> *new-type-id*:
>
> *type-specifier-seq* *new-declarator*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> *new-declarator*:
>
> *ptr-operator* *new-declarator*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> *noptr-new-declarator*
>
> *ptr-operator*:
>
> `*` *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub> *cv-qualifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> `&` *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> `&&` *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> *nested-name-specifier* `*` *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub> *cv-qualifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> *noptr-new-declarator*:
>
> `[` *expression* `]` *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> *noptr-new-declarator* `[` *constant-expression* `]` *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub>

The *new-declarator* grammar symbol used in *new-type-id* is like the *abstract-declarator* symbol used in *type-id*, with three important differences:

- *new-declarator* allows a non-constant expression between the first set of square brackets, to specify dynamic creation of an array with variable size.  *type-id* does not because "array `T` of size `N`" is only a valid C++ type if `N` is a constant expression.
- *type-id* allows enclosing a *ptr-abstract-declarator* in parentheses to help specify a pointer-to-array or pointer-to-function type, and/or enclosing a function parameter list in parentheses to specify a function type.  *new-declarator* does not allow any parentheses at all!  Any parentheses following a `new` keyword specify either a *new-placement*, or a parenthesized *type-id*, or a *new-initializer*.  (I guess if *new-type-id* could also involve parentheses, disambiguating the combinations of all these things would be extremely messy.)
- *type-id* allows the `...` ellipsis token in the place where a real declaration would have an identifier.  Not really relevant here, but this allows unnamed function parameter packs, as in `template<class T> void f(T...);`

So the *new-expression* form using a *type-id* doesn't allow for a variable size, which your example function needs.  And the *new-expression* form using a *new-type-id* doesn't allow any function parameter lists at all in its syntax tree, so any function type must be introduced in the *type-specifier-seq*.  I think the possibilities are a *type-name*, a *decltype-specifier*, or a *typename-specifier*.

So I guess the *decltype-specifier* option does give us another stupidly verbose way of writing the expression, but this time without needing a named type alias or an `#include`.

```
auto p6 = new decltype(static_cast<void(*)()>(nullptr))[n];
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you format grammar productions manually when posting on StackOverflow, or use some tool for this?

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Just typed it in, with some copy-pasting.

Comment: Do we have the same situation when dynamically allocating an array of pointers to an array, e.g. `new std::add_pointer_t<int[5]>[n]` or `new decltype((int(*)[5])0)[n]`?